# Yii - Non-static method PEAR::registerShutdownFunc() should not be called statically

Tags: php, yii

I have function actionView in KategoriController.php

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new Kategori('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Kategori']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Kategori'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

I have tried to change to `public static function actionView` but still the show the same error: Non-static method PEAR::registerShutdownFunc() should not be called statically.

How can I solve this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the linenumber in the error compare to your code sample?

Comment: Check exception trace to see from where actually error produces. USe define('YII_DEBUG',true);

Comment: you have E_STRICT mode enabled for error_reporting, you need to disable that.

Comment: When I view stack trace, I figured out this line `$model=new Kategori('search');` but I don't know how to solve it I think there's nothing wrong with that code

Comment: I think your function registerShutdownFunc() is called like static. You must made this function static, not actionAdmin().

Comment: @gultomicro please add your `Kategori`s `search()` function. There may be something you missed.

Comment: @topher: Oh yes I missed that thing, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Kristiyan registerShutdownFunc() comes from PEAR class if you see Question subject.  Its not ok to guess it is comes from PEAR Library ?